# postgres: why does this GIN index work with 'text%' but not '%text%"?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to index a text column as following:

```
create table tmp_search (a integer primary key,o text);
create index idx_tmp_search on tmp_search using gin (o gin_trgm_ops);

insert into tmp_search (a,o)
select i, 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry''s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum'||i
from generate_series(0, 2000000) i;
```

but the index is only used with `o ILIKE 'text%'` but not `o ILIKE '%text%'`.

Any idea how to make this index works with both cases ?

these are the query plan for both queries:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT o from tmp_search
WHERE o ILIKE '%text%'
LIMIT 10;

Limit  (cost=2253669.35..2253670.54 rows=10 width=583)
  ->  Unique  (cost=2253669.35..2848443.21 rows=4999508 width=583)
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2253669.35..2835944.44 rows=4999508 width=583)
              Workers Planned: 2
              ->  Sort  (cost=2252669.33..2257877.15 rows=2083128 width=583)
                    Sort Key: o
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tmp_search  (cost=0.00..410657.71 rows=2083128 width=583)
                          Filter: (o ~~* '%text%'::text)


EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT o from tmp_search
WHERE o ILIKE 'text%'
LIMIT 10;

Limit  (cost=5130.46..5130.51 rows=10 width=583)
  ->  Unique  (cost=5130.46..5132.96 rows=500 width=583)
        ->  Sort  (cost=5130.46..5131.71 rows=500 width=583)
              Sort Key: o
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tmp_search  (cost=3155.88..5108.04 rows=500 width=583)
                    Recheck Cond: (o ~~* 'text%'::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tmp_search  (cost=0.00..3155.75 rows=500 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (o ~~* 'text%'::text)
```

Comment: Because one returns the entire table making the index worse than useless, and the other doesn't.

Comment: Your test setup won't produce valid insights for any real life table. One pattern matches all, the other none. Start by telling us what you want to find out, exactly. And your Postgres version, obviously.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I'm using PG13.2, the column is supposed to contain at least 2 millions pages URLs, and I want to find for example 10 distinct URLs that contains /users/

Comment: @jjanes: is there a way to fix that, because the column will contains a lot of similar~ich values

Comment: @tahayk  What is there to fix?  The 'problem' is an imaginary one.  There might also be a real problem (why are you storing duplicates if you do not want duplicates?), but you have not properly demonstrated or described it.

Comment: @jjanes I'm storing URLs opened by users during time, that's why I have duplicate values, so basically I have a list of URLs&timestamps